# Login with Facebook or Google+ account

Tags: users, 8

I want users to be able to log in (signup) in site with their Facebook or Google plus account. But I didn't find anything for Drupal 8.

Is there any module or solution for doing this job or I should downgrade and use Drupal 7 in our project?

Answer (score 1):

This specific signup type is called OpenID. And it allows an external login provider to login users on your site.

You can have a look at [OpenID Connect](https://www.drupal.org/project/openid_connect) module. Which has a beta version for Drupal 8 available, and according to the module page already ships with a Google implementation.

> OpenID Connect 1.0 is a simple identity layer on top of the OAuth 2.0
>   protocol. It allows Clients to verify the identity of the End-User
>   based on the authentication performed by an Authorization Server, as
>   well as to obtain basic profile information about the End-User in an
>   interoperable and REST-like manner.

I am not sure about Facebook, but it might be that is in another contrib module or easy to implement yourself. (I didn't look for it.)

Comment: thank you, I take look at it, but it seems not stable and not work with faceook:(

Comment: Pity, but perhaps the term `Open ID` will get you further in your search. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can use module [Simple OAuth](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_oauth). Some more details about it, from its project page:

> ... is an implementation of the OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework: Bearer Token specification.
>
> Using OAuth 2.0 Bearer Token is very easy. See how you can get the basics working in less than a minute!
>
> This project is focused in simplicity of use and flexibility. When deciding which project to use, also consider other projects like [OAuth](https://www.drupal.org/project/oauth), an OAuth 1 implementation that doesn't rely on you having https in your production server.

Comment: Did you read the description of this module?
where mentioned about facebook and google plus?